# Speed up many accesses on 3 dimensional array

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

In a `class Simulation` which is a child of `QThread` I implemented a function, in which I need to access an `array` about 1e9 times.

The `array` is a 3 dimensional `array` (26x13x23) that is implemented as an 1 dimensional `array`. The value of this `array` is read by an `inline member function` of that `class` implemented as:

```
double getValue(int x, int y, int z) {return array[x*Ly*Lz + y*Lz + z;}
```

In another `member function` is a loop which is run through about 1e9 times. The values of `x`, `y` and `z` change randomly.
This takes about 5 to 6 seconds.

Is there any possibility to speed up the access on such an `array` or an alternative that I could use?

Comment: well you can declare array as `array[N1][N2][N3]` and access using `array[x][y][z]`, but the access time would be close because it is just doing index calculation internally

Comment: a minor optimization is pre-multiply Ly*Lz if they are constant in the object (if they are static the compiler probably already does this for you).  other then that not much you can do if it's random... the memory cache will be blown nearly every access.

Comment: Actually I was i a little bit wrong. It takes about 3 to 4 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could add some more context. Accessing the array might not be the bottleneck of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe it is

If each index is sampled uniformly, and index could be rearranged, then you should make fastest changing index (Z?) to have largest dimension, and slowest changing index to have smallest dimension

with modern CPUs (large L3 cache, prefetcher, large cache lines) one has to make code favor linear access

and `x*Ly*Lz + y*Lz + z` better be either changed to `x*Lyz + y*Lz + z` or to `(x*Ly + y)*Lz + z`, you save one multiplication

Comment: The problem is that I can't say which index changes fastest. x, y and z are coordinations of particles over which is iterated many times. However they change position every iteration. I also tried `x*Lyz + y*Lz + z` and `(x*Ly + y)*Lz + z` but both is slower (the second one even much slower).

Comment: Well, in your code Z is the fastest index, because `z` and `z+1` are neighbours in memory. X, from the other hand, is the slowest index, it is plane index, going from `x` to `x+1` will move you by Ly*Lz items.

Comment: Thus I would propose to have layout with 13 planes in X, 23 rows in Y and 36 in Z. Think about it in this way: one out of 13 samples will give you same plane index which is good, likely to be cached. One in 23 samples will give you same row index. And then you are in linear part, where prefetcher works and cache line with 64bytes might already have you data...

Comment: I tried swapping indices so x has the largest index but that didn't really speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1**

Shifting is faster than multiplying and bitwise or is faster that addition. If you can afford to throw away some memory to make access faster, try that one:

- x: 26 <= 32 (5 bits)
- y: 13 <= 16 (4 bits)
- z: 23 <= 32 (5 bits)

Now you can store you index in that binary pattern:

```
bit      |13|12|11|10| 9| 8| 7| 6| 5| 4| 3| 2| 1| 0|
variable |      x       |     y     |       z      |
```

Now you do

```
array[(x<<9) | (y<<5) | z];
```

That will block you 2^14 times size of a double instead of 7774, i.e. twice the memory.

**Idea 2**

The inline keyword is basically a hint to the compiler that might be ignored. To be safe that there is no function call in any optimization level, you can use a macro:

```
#include <iostream>

static double array[1<<14]; // 2^14 elements

inline double getValue(int x, int y, int z) {
    return array[(x<<9) | (y<<5) | z];
}

#define getValueMacro(x, y, z) (array[(x<<9) | (y<<5) | z])


int main()
{
    array[(1<<9) | (2<<5) | 3] = 3.14;

    double a = getValue(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    double b = getValueMacro(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shifting bitwise did speed things up a little bit. Instead of about 3.5 seconds the process takes 3.3 seconds now.

Answer (score 0):

If values of `x`, `y`, `z` change randomly, you're picking a random element of the set.

Something like:

```
double getValue()
{
  constexpr unsigned sup(26 * 13 * 23);
  thread_local std::mt19937 e;

  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> d(0, sup - 1);

  return array[d(e)];
}
```

is faster.

---

If you mean random access, you could reshape the array from 26x13x23 to 26x16x32. In this way it'll be simpler to compute the index (some locations won't be used).

By "reshaping" I mean that the new size of `array` should be 26x16x32 = 13312 (instead of 7774):

```
double array[26*16*32];
```

Index computation is simpler since:

```
x * Ly * Lz + y * Lz + z
```

becomes

```
x * 16 * 32 + y * 32 + z // i.e. x << 9 + y << 5 + z
```

Any decent compiler will optimize the expression using bitwise operators if it's helpful.

**BUT** the array will be bigger and it could have adverse effects on cache (you should try and measure).